# What does "It's shared live" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, definition

It's from "Green Room" movie. An interviewer asks members of an underground punk band about social media peresence and their music, so the bassist answers: "When you take it all virtual, you lose the texture. Just... you gotta be there. The music is for effect. It's time and aggression... Technical wizardry. And **it's shared live** and then it's over. The energy can't last."

Now, "share" is to have a portion of smoething with the others as it says in Oxford Dictionaries. But what the definition of "live" in that context? Is it the same as "life"? The pronouncing is same for both, but I'm still not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the bassist is being "pure" to his music. He's saying that the music that they play is best shared (with the audience) live - that is, the audience is in the same place as the band.

The effect of listening to the music over social media means that the whole atmosphere of the room where the music is played "live" is lost.

"Live" with respect to music is usually the opposite of "recorded" - but with today's streaming over the Internet, listening to the music at almost the same time that it is being played is "almost live".

Answer (score 2):

> [share](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/share)
>   2 a :  to partake of, use, experience, occupy, or enjoy with others
>   [live](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/live)
>   done in front of an audience : of or involving a play, concert, etc., that is performed in front of people

This *live* is pronounced /laɪv/ or \ˈlīv\. It rhymes with [*hive*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hive).

So the music, the experience, the effect, time and aggression are being experienced/felt/enjoyed by the audience **in person**.